# Concurrency of lines

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

If the three lines:
$$x\sin^2 \theta + y \cos^2 \theta = 1$$
$$x \cos^2 \theta + y \sin^2 \theta = 1$$
$$lx + my + n = 0$$
are concurrent then which of the following is true?

a) $l+m=n$

b) $l^3+m^3+n^3=3lmn$

c) $l=m=n$

d) None of these

Well obviously if the lines are concurrent, then all three terms have to be in a common ratio. However don't know where to proceed from there. Please help!

Comment: Use determinant.

Comment: Hmmm?? No idea how to use that. @TroyWoo

Comment: Note that we have $l^3+m^3+n^3=3lmn+(l+m+n)(l^2+m^2+n^2-lm-mn-nl)$ which is a cubic identity worth knowing.

Comment: @MarkBennet Ummmm.... lost you there. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: It relates to whether or not $b)$ is true

Comment: Yeah lol I realized that. Thanks though! I can definitely pester my teacher about this one :D

Answer (score 1):

Solving for $x,y$ from the first two equation, we find $x=y=1$

So for concurrency, $lx+my+n=0$ must pass through $(1,1)$

Comment: Hmmm... How exactly did you solve for $x,y$?

Comment: @Gummybears, Do you know how to solve for two unknowns from two linear simultaneous equation

Comment: Yes of course. But in this it'll be kinda hard o.O

Comment: Note: Except for the case where $\sin \theta = \pm \cos \theta$ when $x+y=2$ and the two first lines are identical

Comment: @MarkBennet, I was going to add. I think the question should have included that implicit condition

Comment: I agree it is an odd question otherwise.

Comment: Well it has the option of none of these :P

Comment: @Gummybears, Then we should have to write Option $$(b)$$ if $\cos2\theta\ne0$  $$(d)$$ otherwise

Comment: Oh? Ummm... Wiat I think I lost you there. How exactly is (b) true?

Comment: @Gummybears, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543991/factorize-the-polynomial-x3y3z3-3xyz?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

The three lines are concurrent iff the determinant of 
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
s^2& c^2& -1\\
c^2& s^2& -1\\
l& m& n
\end{array}
\right]
$$
is equal to zero. You shall have $l+m+n=0$ or $s^2-c^2=0$.

Comment: Ohhh..... Well that's a good thing to know.

Comment: @Gummybears, http://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/geometry/condition-for-concurrency-of-three-straight-lines.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather than solving the equations lets try something else - since the conditions are independent of $\theta$, we can choose $\theta$ as we please.

If $\theta =0$ the first two equations give $y=1$ and $x=1$ and the third gives $l+m+n=0$. So we can have $l=m=1, n=-2$ which eliminate $a)$ and $c)$. But $b)$ becomes $-6=-6$ which is true.

Now if $\sin \theta = \cos \theta =\frac {\sqrt 2}2$ we get $x+y=2$ from the first two equations. Then if $x=0, y=2$ the third equation becomes $n=-2m$. Setting $m=n=0, l=1$ note that $b)$ becomes $1=0$, so can't always hold.