# Name for the identity $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-zy)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

> Within the math literature written in Portuguese and Spanish (at least), the identity

$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-zy)$$

is often referred as being "Gauss identity", but I haven't seen this identity with this name in the math literature in English.

Question: is there any base to call this identity "Gauss identity"? is there any specific name for it?

Comment: I think it's the Euler's identity.

Comment: And you can use [Newton's identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543991/factorize-the-polynomial-x3y3z3-3xyz) to prove it...

Comment: Identité de Gauss in French.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with any name for it.

Note, taking $\omega^3 = 1$ but $\omega \neq 1,$ so that $\omega^2 + \omega = -1,$
$$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - yz - zx - xy = (x+y \omega + z \omega^2)(x+y \omega^2 + z \omega)  $$

The general rule involved: take your homogeneous ternary cubic. Write down the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives. The entries of this matrix are linear in the variables.   Finally, take the determinant, call that $\mathcal H.$

The theorem is this: the original form, call it $f(x,y,z),$ factors completely into three linear factors (over the complex numbers) if and only if $\mathcal H$ is a constant multiple of $f.$

G. Brookfield:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an article in the American Mathematical Monthly calling this identity **Gauss's Gem**, see [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263135920_Generalizing_Gauss%27s_Gem).
So I suppose, Spanish and English have something in common concerning this identity.