# Can the expression $\alpha^{2κ-1}+\beta^{2κ-1}+\gamma^{2κ-1}\;$ be factorized

Tags: polynomials, factoring

[image][image]
Is there an equation for the first picture, which fatorizes it in a similar fashion as the second pictures equation is factorized
If so can you please tell me which equation it is and where I could find similar ones
All the letters above are integers and ν in the second picture Is odd
Thanking you in advance

Comment: No, because of Fermat. But a similar expression can be factored, here is an example for exponent $3$:[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543991/factorize-the-polynomial-x3y3z3-3xyz?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: thank you for the answer, i will keep it in mind