# If $x = b+c-a$, $y = c+a-b$, $z = a+b-c$, prove $x^3+y^3+z^3 - 3xyz = 4(a^3+b^3+c^3 -3abc)$

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, factoring, symmetric-polynomials

I got this problem in a book. While trying to solve this I got something like

$$2(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$
 and can't move forward.
Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543991/factorize-the-polynomial-x3y3z3-3xyz).

Comment: Try expanding everything and then reverse-engineering it.

Comment: Hint:  Note that $x+y+z=a+b+c$, $x-y=2(b-a)$, $y-z=2(c-b)$, and $z-x=2(a-c)$.  Use Dietrich Burde's link.  And note that $$p^2+q^2+r^2-pq-qr-rp=\frac{(p-q)^2+(q-r)^2+(r-p)^2}{2}.$$

Comment: @WETutorialSchool What you wrote as Hint is complete solution

Comment: @Maverick  FWIW, I saw a meta post that it is controversial to leave hints as answers.  :D

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{cyc}(x^3-xyz)=(x+y+z)\sum_{cyc}(x^2-xy)=$$
$$=(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}((a+b-c)^2-(a+b-c)(a+c-b))=$$
$$=(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(3a^2-2ab-a^2+b^2+c^2-2bc)=$$
$$=4(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(a^2-ab)=4(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc).$$
I used $$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$F=(x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz)=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)~~~~(1)$$
$$(x+y+z)=(a+b+c)~~~~(2)$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=[b^2+c^2+a^2+2bc-2ab-2ac+c^2+a^2+b^2+2ac-2ab-2bc+a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab-2ac-2bc]=[3(a^2+b^2+c^2)-2(ab+bc+ca)]~~~~(3)$$
$$xy+yz+zx=c^2-a^2-b^2+2ab+a^2-b^2-c^2+2bc+c^2-a^2-b^2+2ab$$
$$=[-(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2(ab+bc+ca)]~~~~~(4)$$
So from using (2), (3) and (4) in (1), we get
$$F=x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=4(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc).$$

Answer (score 0):

Note $x+y+z=a+b+c=s$. Then,

$$x^3+y^3+z^3 = (x+y+z)^3-3(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)=s^3-24abc$$

$$3xyz = 3(s-2a)(s-2b)(s-2c)= -3s^3 + 12(ab +bc +ca)s -24abc $$

and

\begin{align}
x^3+y^3+z^3 - 3xyz 
 = 4s^3-12(ab +bc +ca)s
=4(a^3+b^3+c^3 -3abc)
\end{align}